# opening .js file in CMD runs windows script host

Tags: javascript, cmd.exe, ffmpeg, windows-10

I am installing ffmpeg for node.js.
When i run ffmpeg by the following command in CMD; ffmpeg -codecs
It opens a .js file with windows script host instead of CMD.

This is because i accidentally pressed windows script host as standard program for .js files.

I am running this on windows 10 and i cannot find a way to reverse my actions..
i have tried select CMD as standard program for opening javascript files but this didnt work. It gave me an error that this file type could not be associated with the program chosen.

I dont know what to do.

Comment: CMD knows nothing about executing javascript. The Windows Scripting Host is the engine for executing or debugging various scripting languages. It can be started via cscript.exe (console) or wscript.exe (GUI). Run `cscript //H:CScript` to change the default to cscript.exe. Then .js scripts will run with an attached console, which is not CMD. It's just that you're used to getting a console by first running CMD and have mistakenly assumed they're the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can write `ffmpeg.cmd` instead of just `ffmpeg`.

Or you can stop CMD to automatically interpret JS files as executables. To do this, remove .JS from the PATHEXT environment variable.